# Issues Fetching Proper Listings' Data Using RETS

Tags: php, api, ddf

I am trying tot download a live feed of property listings from the CREA's DDF. I am making an API request via PHP to their DDF and am pulling and downloading all the recent listings into my DB. This works fine, the issue is my clients listings which are in the DDF and should be pulled with all the other listings are not being pulled. I seem to get what it seems like all the listings for the surrounding area, but maybe not since I can't receive my client's listings which should be a part of the pull. When I talked to CREA people they said my clients listings are in the DDF so I should be able to pull them with all the other listings. I was hoping to get some advice from some people who have a better understanding of making request like this, or even better using CREA's DDF.

I will provide my code below, I will try to only include stuff that would be relevant and take out the unnecessary code to make this a little easier. If you want to see more of the code, I will add those parts on request.

If I understand correctly I need to add onto my paramaters array but I really dont know why my request is doing this so any help would be awesome!

Here is the code for my download.php file

```
$TimeBackPull = "-24 hours"; 

/* RETS Variables */
require("PHRets_CREA.php");
$RETS = new PHRets();
$RETSURL = "http://data.crea.ca/Login.svc/Login";
$RETSUsername = "**********************";
$RETSPassword = "**********************";
$RETS->Connect($RETSURL, $RETSUsername, $RETSPassword);
$RETS->AddHeader("RETS-Version", "RETS/1.7.2");
$RETS->AddHeader('Accept', '/');
$RETS->SetParam('compression_enabled', true);
$RETS_PhotoSize = "LargePhoto";
$RETS_LimitPerQuery = 100;
if($debugMode /* DEBUG OUTPUT */)
{
    $RETS->SetParam("catch_last_response", true);
    $RETS->SetParam("debug_file", "CREA_Anthony.txt");
    $RETS->SetParam("debug_mode", true);
}

$DBML = "(LastUpdated=" . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($TimeBackPull)) . ")";
$params = array("Limit" => 1, "Format" => "STANDARD-XML", "Count" => 1);
$results = $RETS->SearchQuery("Property", "Property", $DBML, $params);
$totalAvailable = $results["Count"];
for($i = 0; $i < ceil($totalAvailable / $RETS_LimitPerQuery); $i++)
{
    $startOffset = $i*$RETS_LimitPerQuery;

    $params = array("Limit" => $RETS_LimitPerQuery, "Format" => "STANDARD-XML", "Count" => 1, "Offset" => $startOffset);
    $results = $RETS->SearchQuery("Property", "Property", $DBML, $params);          
    foreach($results["Properties"] as $listing)
    {
       //Do Some Stuff
    }
}
```

Here is what my current request looks like in the return xml file

```
http://data.crea.ca/Search.svc/Search?SearchType=Property&Class=Property&Query=%28LastUpdated%3D2015-09-22%29&QueryType=DMQL2&Count=1&Format=STANDARD-XML&Limit=1&StandardNames=0
```

Another thing is that the CREA people said there should be around 1900 active listings to pull but when I count the results I only get around 182 right now

Answer (score 1):

Did you get this resolved?

CREA DDF is weird animal. They only partially support the RETS spec, not fully. They've designed their system around "Destinations" (aka, "Data Feeds") and "Tech Provider" separations.

1) Each of your clients creates one or more data feeds, each of which is assigned a unique DestinationID. When setting up the feed, they select you as the Tech Provider, so their listings get included in your feed, too.

2) You, as the tech provider, have a single feed where you can pull all listings across all of your clients. Where this breaks down, though, is that each listing does not reference which feed/destination that it belongs to. You need to pull data in the context of a particular destination, and then manually associate the current DestinationID with the listings that come through.

CREA thinks that they've made it simpler by having a single Tech Provider feed, but they've actually made it more difficult because they are providing incomplete data on the responses. You, as the developer, need to manually do the associations at your end.

Are your clients selecting you as their Technology Provider during the setup of their Data Feeds? Do you see their feeds show in your Destinations table?

Comment: sorry this is a bit off topic but do you know if CREA DDF is able to request multiple Objects (Photos) at the same time. I am unable to do anything other than pass in a single ListingKey which seems a bit crazy, especially when initializing a new database and having to download 10's of thousands of records.

Comment: @GifCo - Yes, DDF supports retrieving both single photos and multi-part requests using standard RETS GetObject() calls. They do not yet support fetching URLs, but that is in the pipeline.

Comment: thanks so much for getting back to me. Just to confirm when you say multi-part requests are supported do you mean a GetObject() call that returns all the photos for a single listing? Or does it actually support getting all photos for multiple listings in a single call?